# Trying to center "navBar", but width is automatically setting to 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my navigation bar at the top of the page, but the navigation bar's width has automatically set to 100%.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navBar">
            <li><a href="#">List Item #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List Item #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List Item #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List Item #4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List Item #5</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.container{
    width:75%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.navBar{
    width:auto;
    height:35px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Is there another way I could do this so the "navBar" div will align in the center of the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid. `li` must be children of `ul`

`ul` and `div` are block-level elements and so are 100% wide automatically so you have to make them shrink-wrap.

One method is to use `display:inline-block`.

Then `text-align:center` on the parent element will center the contents. Since you have set a height on the `navBar` element, I assume you would want the same on the `li`.

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.navBar {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
}
.navBar li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="navBar">
    <li><a href="#">List Item #1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item #2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item #3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item #4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">List Item #5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that currently .navBar is display:block meaning that it will fill 100% of it's container.

Try setting .navBar to either display:inline-block or float:left

Answer (score 0):

using margin:auto on an object with a width will center it.

Here you go:

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.navBar {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}
li {
  width:18%;
  margin:auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navBar">
      <li><a href="#">Item #1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item #2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item #3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item #4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item #5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Correct markup

`.navBar` needs to be an `ul` instead of a `div` as the parent of the `li`'s to be valid markup :)

### Issue

The default display for `div` and `ul` elements is `display: block`. Elements with `display: block` will be 100% the width of their parent element, rendering `margin: auto` useless. You could set a width on the element to allowing centering but this will break if/when the content changes

### Fix

An easy fix is to use `display: table` as this will allow you to use `margin: auto` to center the element without specifying a width making your code more robust.

Note: *ensure that you remove the default padding from the `ul` otherwise it will not be correctly centered.*

### Example below:

```css
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navBar {
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
}

.navBar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navBar">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```